# Script to position chart misaligns when sheet isn't active?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that essentially renders/updates an entire page, including two charts on it. These charts are positioned dynamically using the `.top` property. I write my scripts intentionally independent of the users currently selected sheet, so there is no `.Select` or `.Activate` here.

This is the expected result, which works fine when the sheet is active:
[image: Charts position themselves properly according to the code]

Notice the *Immediate* window in the bottom-right. This debug shows the calculation that determined what each chart's `.Top` property is, which determines the vertical position.

The first (Spending) chart's `.Top` property:

```
Sheets("Overview").Shapes.Range(Array("Spending_Chart")).Top = _
        Sheets("Overview").Shapes.Range(Array("Add_Category_Button")).Top + 22
        
Debug.Print "1st:  " & _
        Sheets("Overview").Shapes.Range(Array("Add_Category_Button")).Top & _
        " + 22" & _
        " = " & _
        Sheets("Overview").Shapes.Range(Array("Spending_Chart")).Top
' Note: The Add_Category_Button.Top property is consistent and doesn't change.
```

The second (Income) chart's `.Top` property:

```
Sheets("Overview").Shapes.Range(Array("Earning_Chart")).Top _
        = Sheets("Overview").Shapes.Range(Array("Spending_Chart")).Top + _
            Sheets("Overview").Shapes.Range(Array("Spending_Chart")).Height
            
Debug.Print "2nd:  " & _
        Sheets("Overview").Shapes.Range(Array("Spending_Chart")).Top & _
        " + " & _
        Sheets("Overview").Shapes.Range(Array("Spending_Chart")).Height & _
        " = " & _
        Sheets("Overview").Shapes.Range(Array("Earning_Chart")).Top
```

The second chart's position is determined by the bottom (`.Top` + `.Height`) of the first chart. They stack directly on top of eachother.

However, when I run this script while on a different sheet, this is the result:
[image: The calculation's values are correct, but the result is incorrect]

First chart aligns fine, but the second one is miscalculated.
My confusion is, looking at the debug, the values it retrieves to calculate the `.Top` are correct, but the result isn't. 
Also, when I run this function on each sheet, they consistently deliver unique results per sheet:

[image: Different sheets return different results.]

One sheet even messed with the 1st chart calculation.

**What part of my code is relying on the currently selected sheet?** I don't see anything, so it may be some sort of Excel behavior I don't understand.

**Edit**
Here's the code used to place the `Add_Category_Button` shape, which is the only other context there is regarding positioning the charts. I don't see how this could be useful but it was requested.

```
Sheets("Overview").Shapes.Range(Array("Add_Category_Button")).Top = _
        Sheets("Overview").Range("B" & Functions.GetCategoryCount + _
        Functions.GetAccountCount + 6).Top + 4
```

The `GetCategoryCount` and `GetAccountCount` functions run a `CountA` worksheet function on a range inside of another sheet, and return that value. Throughout the screenshots provided, those numbers have been the same each time, so it wouldn't relate to the odd positioning issues.
**Note:** The CountA functions are ran without 'selecting' any other sheets or ranges, so the context of the VBA interpreter doesn't change.

Other than that information, none of the rest of the code relates to positioning the charts, so I don't see a reason to dump it here.

Comment: This is VBA not VBScript.

Comment: It appears from the gif that the code posted above is part of a larger subroutine.  Try moving the code in question into its own subroutine and testing it by itself.

Comment: @TinMan Just tested that, doesn't seem to make a difference. Tried calling within the original sub, as well as running it alone.

Comment: Do you possibly have more than one chart named after "Spending_Chart" in "Overview" sheet?

Comment: BTW, its seems that you get the only right calculation when the active sheet is "1-16 to 1-14": you may want to: 1) add a debug.print right before the relevant chart .Top setting and see if its result fits your expectations 2) set a code break before the relevant chart .Top setting and use Immediate Window to query all relevant values at each code line processing

Comment: @user3598756 didn't even notice that the calculation is correct there! Very odd behavior indeed. Only one Spending_Chart, every chart in the workbook has a unique name. I'll play with these solutions either today or tomorrow and get back to ya

Comment: Show us the actual code youuse to set the chart positions.  Without that, any answer is just speculation

Comment: @chrisneilsen Done, but it doesn't help anything really. All relevant context was included in the original post, unless there is some weird excel/vba quirk relating to the `Add_Category_Button`'s positioning. But that button and the first chart didn't really have any issues, so I don't think that's the case.

Comment: @josh  I tried, but I cannot reproduce this issue using the code you've provided.

Comment: @josh I suggest (for your own sake and for the sake of this Q) you create a [MRE] that only deals with positioniong the charts (ie use only .Top and .Height and removes reliance on your other functions).  If you can't reproduce it doing that, well, you'll know where to look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without more of your code. Your snippet works fine on my sample workbook. I don't think this is a code problem as much as an Excel/VBA bug you are hitting. More on that below.

One quick comment up front... I don't like your syntax of `Shapes.Range(Array("Add_Category_Button"))`. I would prefer the shorter `Shapes("Add_Category_Button")` but both work the same for me.

Here is my test routine:

```
Sub my_test()
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Activate
    
        Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Name
        Sheets("Overview").Shapes("Pie_Chart").Top = _
            Sheets("Overview").Shapes("Add_Category_Button").Top + 22
            
        Debug.Print "1st:  " & _
            Sheets("Overview").Shapes("Add_Category_Button").Top & _
            " + 22 = " & _
            Sheets("Overview").Shapes("Pie_Chart").Top
    
        Sheets("Overview").Shapes("Column_Chart").Top = _
            Sheets("Overview").Shapes("Pie_Chart").Top + _
            Sheets("Overview").Shapes("Pie_Chart").Height
                
        Debug.Print "2nd:  " & _
            Sheets("Overview").Shapes("Pie_Chart").Top & _
            " + " & _
            Sheets("Overview").Shapes("Pie_Chart").Height & _
            " = " & _
            Sheets("Overview").Shapes("Column_Chart").Top
    Next i
End Sub
```

And my result:

```
Overview
1st:  64 + 22 = 86
2nd:  86 + 216 = 302
Interval
1st:  64 + 22 = 86
2nd:  86 + 216 = 302
1-16 to 1-14
1st:  64 + 22 = 86
2nd:  86 + 216 = 302
1-17 to 1-15
1st:  64 + 22 = 86
2nd:  86 + 216 = 302
Control
1st:  64 + 22 = 86
2nd:  86 + 216 = 302
```

I tried using different view percentages and got consistent results, though the numbers above changed any time I altered the view percentage on the **Overview** sheet.

I did find I could create some wrong results if I had 2 windows of the same workbook open via **View > New Window**:

```
Interval
1st:  75.33331 + 22 = 114.6666
2nd:  114.6666 + 258.5001 = 445.3889
1-16 to 1-14
1st:  75.33331 + 22 = 114.6666
2nd:  114.6666 + 310.5001 = 508.9445
1-17 to 1-15
1st:  75.33331 + 22 = 114.6666
2nd:  114.6666 + 374.0557 = 584.0556
Control
1st:  75.33331 + 22 = 114.6666
2nd:  114.6666 + 449.1668 = 676.5002
```

In my case, I think the height of the chart was changing after setting the `.top` property. If you have more than one window or form open, I could imagine that you could have a similar issue. This was very finicky and hard to replicate, but I suspect it has to do with situations where `.top` was changed with different windows and view percentages involved. When I just had one window and no forms my results were solid.

In my file, the chart height and width seemed to be altered as well, and I was seeing issues where the chart rendered improperly (for example, the selection box was a different size than the chart as displayed, or part of the chart was truncated). This is why I think this may be a bug.

The rendering errors always reset when I reset the chart size, so maybe try also setting the height/width in your code?

```
    Sheets("Overview").Shapes("Add_Category_Button").Top = 58
    Sheets("Overview").Shapes("Add_Category_Button").Height = 22
    Sheets("Overview").Shapes("Pie_Chart").Height = 200
    Sheets("Overview").Shapes("Pie_Chart").Width = 300
    Sheets("Overview").Shapes("Column_Chart").Height = 200
    Sheets("Overview").Shapes("Column_Chart").Width = 300
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer here. It really does seem to be buggy behavior in excel and not an issue with the code logic. Statically setting the `.Height` seemed to do the trick mostly, but theres still some odd issues with the charts overlapping. I fixed this by avoiding using the FirstSheet's `.Top` and `.Height` in the second sheet's calculation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the two sheets in your example are at different zoom levels, theorizing this may be an excel bug:

Have you tried with the zoom levels set the same on the active sheet and the sheet containing the plot? If that works you could try getting the location of two vertically adjacent cells on both sheets and then using the difference of the .top values as the 'row height' on each sheet and using the ratio between the active sheet and the target plot's sheets row height as a conversion factor.

Another thought (an ugly kludge, since the row height difference is probably not accurate enough) is that you could turn application.screenupdating off (if it's not already 'false'), then create a plot on the active page and get its height and width, then compare that to the height and width of a new plot on the target sheet (and use that for the conversion factor).

Comment: @Tom2355524 also, I have tested with Application.Screenupdating off, no difference

Comment: Zoom levels do not seem to effect the positioning/coordinates

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with not updating "graphically", try making the graph(s) invisible at the beginning of the code and visible again at the end:

```
With Sheets("Overview").ChartObjects("Spending_Chart")
    .Visible = False
    'Do all your stuff including setting the .Top
    .Visible = True
End With
```

Comment: Interesting idea, I'll give this a shot later tonight

Comment: Didn't make a difference unfortunately

Comment: Unfortunate, these Charts are already there? You only move/adjust them? Maybe you can add more code to your opening post.(involving the placement of these charts) what happens when you step (F8) through your code?

Comment: The placement of the first chart is determined based on constant variables, and is correct. The second chart's placement is based on the first one's position and height. Seems that The calculation isn't able to read the first chart's position for some reason. I could add more code but I don't think it would really help. Stepping through doesn't seem to reveal anything new unfortunately